# Node.js express, ejs, request - show spinning wheel while doing request

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, node-request

I'm using request https://github.com/request/request. Is it possible to show a spinning wheel in the frontend while doing the request? Let's say unhide a spinning wheel? If yes, how to do so?

As of right now I'm showing an alert message uppon success or error ...

```
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    request.get({
        headers: {
            "authorization": auth
        },
        url: "localhost/abc/search?name=peter"
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
            return console.dir(error);
        }
      var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);

      if(jsonBody.status === 200) {
        console.log('Request successful!');
        req.flash('success', 'Database search successful! :)')
        res.redirect('/search')
        }
      if(jsonBody.success === false) {
        console.log('Request not successful!');
        req.flash('error', 'Request not successful! :(')
        res.redirect('/search')
      }
    });
});
```

As frontend i'm using ejs:

```
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="card card-container">
        <h2 class='login_title text-center'><%= page %></h2>
        <hr>

        <form class="form-container" method="post" action="/search">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        <% if (messages.success) { %>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <%= messages.success %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% if (messages.error) { %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <%= messages.error %>
            </div>
        <% } %>

      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it looks like you are sending a post request to the same url and attaching data to the response to do your flash messaging.

It's impossible to have this spinning wheel using the request system you are right now, however I would point you towards learning AJAX (Fetch API/Axios are good libraries to simplify this a little).

This basically allows you to make requests without reloading the page and then your data is returned as javascript variables that you can access.

So for example: you submit your form, you have an event handler that stops your form doing the regular request and instead does an ajax request. As soon as that ajax request is sent off, you set your loading wheel to spin (by first hiding and then display:block or some other method). Your ajax request has a callback for when it is finished. In that callback you have access to the data from the request and can continue from there.

The other thing to note is that with this method, it's more reasonable to return variables in JSON than it is to return standard HTML and then create any HTML you need via javascript using those variables and place them in your HTML.

[This is a good site to learn AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), The code may look a bit long form but the libraries mentioned above will turn this into just a few lines.

Comment: Better answer given :)